# How to round down if less than .26 and up if .26 or greater to the full year. I.e. 46.23 => 46; 46.26 => 47

Tags: c#, rounding

How to round down if less than .26 and up if .26 or greater to the full year.  I.e. 46.23 => 46; 46.26 => 47 in c#

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a "giv me teh codez" site. You should create an [mcve] and show at least minimum of effort trying to resolve your issue.

Comment: Just use `Math.Round(x+0.24)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the decimal digits from the number and check your condition 
if is greater than 26 or not 
example

```
private static double RoundExample(this decimal number ){
var decimalDigits = number - Convert.ToInt32(number);
if(decimalDigits > 0.26m)
 return Math.Ceiling(number);
else 
return Math.Floor(number);
}
```

Comment: this piece of code to get the decimalDigits is wrong, it will not always return the correct value of decimalDigits since Convert.ToInt32 rounds the value before returning it. The below piece of code returns the decimalDigits correctly. var decimalDigits = number - (int)number;